# Media/Template folder fills up with constantly generating css and js files with 8 random characters appended to filenames

Tags: css, .htaccess-configuration

One of my site's media/template folder continues to generate new css and js files every few days.  Each file is appended with an 8-character string of random alphanumeric characters.

What I expect to see:
stylesheet.css

What I actually see:
stylesheet.ga83laE2.css

The site functions fine, but because new files are generated every few days, I end up having to go in and delete files (assuming they are older versions).  I suspect this is due to htaccess mod_rewrite or a template's compression scheme, but for the life of me I can't figure out the cause.  I thought it was the debug plugin, but switched that off.

Any ideas on the source of this?  Or why Joomla isn't automatically deleting the older files when it creates new ones?

Thanks

Comment: Congrats on taking the bold step of posting a question as a new user.  Please take the [tour].  When you have time, please browse the site and see if you can help to resolve someone else's issue.  When we all give, we all win.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a function of the template designed to ensure website visitors are seeing the latest version of the stylesheet (rather than a cached copy which may be outdated).

Check the settings in the template to see if you have any control over this or check with the template developer for advice.

Comment: It's Nano3 from Yootheme and I have it's compression for JS and CSS turned on.  I'll try turning it off. Thanks for your reply!